# Change component based on URL segment in Vue / Inertiajs

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

So I want to change a component based on the first URL segment. I found this:

```
computed: {
    path: function() {
        const firstSegment = (new URL(window.location.href)).pathname.split('/')[1];
        return `${firstSegment}`;
    }
}
```

It indeed gives me the correct segment when I go to `mydomain/users`, the output of `{{ path }}` is indeed `users`. When going to another page, for example `mydomain/contacts`, the `{{ path }}` output does not change to `contacts`.

For now I am just playing around with this and I just want to understand why it isn't changing. Perhaps computed isn't the way to go?

PS. I am trying to update a component to include a sidebar menu based on the URL segment, like so:

```
<component :is="path"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I suggest using the `$page.url` or the `usePgae()` hook to achieve this, check the Active states section [here](https://inertiajs.com/links) for more information